# Possible to display two query results side by side in LinqPad?

Tags: linqpad

I am wondering if it is possible to display two query results side by side instead of top to bottom in LinqPad?
i.e. the same record pulled with two different queries so that I can look at the side by side to compare data?

Comment: You could combine the results into one `IEnumerable` i.e. using a `join`? Is it just one record or a table of records?

Answer (score 0):

Using some extension methods, you can convert any `Object` to a `Dictionary<string,object>` that represents the fields and properties and their values. Then you can join them.

Some extension methods on `Type` and `MemberInfo` makes it easier to work with properties and fields together:

```
public static class TypeExt {
    public static MemberInfo[] GetPropertiesOrFields(this Type t, BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) =>
        t.GetMembers(bf).Where(mi => mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field | mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property).ToArray();
}

public static class MemberInfoExt {
    public static object GetValue(this MemberInfo member, object srcObject) {
        switch (member) {
            case FieldInfo mfi:
                return mfi.GetValue(srcObject);
            case PropertyInfo mpi:
                return mpi.GetValue(srcObject);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo or PropertyInfo", nameof(member));
        }
    }
}
```

With those helpers, you can convert an `object` to a `Dictionary<string,object>`:

```
public static class ObjectExt {
    public static IDictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(this object item) {
        if (item is IDictionary<string, object> id)
            return id;
        else {
            var dictAnsObj = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            foreach (var prop in item.GetType().GetPropertiesOrFields()) {
                try {
                    dictAnsObj.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(item));
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    dictAnsObj.Add(prop.Name, ex);
                }
            }

            return dictAnsObj;
        }
    }

    public class SideBySideClass {
        public string Key;
        public object Left;
        public object Right;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<SideBySideClass> SideBySide(this object left, object right) {
        return left.ToDictionary()
                   .Join(right.ToDictionary(),
                         kvp => kvp.Key,
                         kvp => kvp.Key,
                         (l, r) => new SideBySideClass() { Key = l.Key, Left = l.Value, Right = r.Value })
                   .OrderBy(sxs => sxs.Key);
    }
}
```

With the `object`s converted to two dictionaries, it is easy to join them on member names and then LINQPad will output them side by side. If `r1` and `r2` are your single records, then:

```
r1.SideBySide(r2).Dump();
```

will output them side by side.

Using some small changes you can add another column to show which values are different.

You could also `join` two sets of records on some id field and output them side by side. Here is an extension method for that:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<SideBySideClass>> SidesBySides<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> lefts, IEnumerable<T> rights, Func<T,TKey> keyFn) =>
    lefts.Join(rights, keyFn, keyFn, (l, r) => l.SideBySide(r));
```

Answer (score 0):

A lightweight option is to make a Tuple array of them and go from there:

```
Person a = GetA();
Person b = GetB();

Tuple<Person, Person> tup = new Tuple<Person, Person>(a, b);
Tuple<Person, Person>[] tupArray = new[] { tup };
tupArray.Dump(1);
```